# using formGroup for 2 filters

Tags: angular, typescript, angular4-forms

I'm using form to filter the relevant products from price filter:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <select name="Price" formControlName="filterProduct">
      <option *ngFor="let k of PriceFilter; let i = index;"
        [ngValue]="getValue(i)">
        {{ getValue(i).displayText }}
      </option>
    </select>
</form>
       <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let product of filteredProducts">
            <img src={{product.ProductImage}}>
            <p>store: {{ store?.StoreName }}</p>
            <p>Product Price: {{ product.Price }}</p>
          <p>Product Title: {{ product.ProductTitle }}</p>

        </li>
      </ul>
```

.ts:

```
myForm: FormGroup;
constructor(private _storeService:StoreService,private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      filterProduct: ['']
    })}
getValue(index) {
    if(index === 0)
      return { 
        lower: 0, 
        displayText: this.PriceFilter[index].DisplayText, 
        upper: this.PriceFilter[index].Value 
      };
    else {
      return { 
        lower: this.PriceFilter[index - 1].Value, 
        upper: this.PriceFilter[index].Value,
        displayText: `${this.PriceFilter[index - 1].DisplayText} - ${this.PriceFilter[index].DisplayText}`
      };
    }
  }
ngOnInit() {
    this._storeService.getProducts()
   .subscribe(data =>{
   this.myForm.get('filterProduct').valueChanges.subscribe(
        value => {
          console.log(value);
          this.filteredProducts = [...this.Stores[0].Products.filter(product => product.Price >= value.lower && product.Price <= value.upper )]
        }
      )

       });
```

PriceFilter looks like:

```
      PriceFilter = [
{
      "TagId": 20,
      "Type": "Budget",
      "Value": 25,
      "Values": null,
      "DisplayText": "$25",
      "Order": null
    },
    {
      "TagId": 21,
      "Type": "Budget",
      "Value": 50,
      "Values": null,
      "DisplayText": "$50",
      "Order": null
    }]
```

I have gender filter that looks very similar, I want the filter that will present the relevant products if the gender filter and the product have the same tag id, not the range of price, how can I add another filter to the same form? [gender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeGao.png)

Comment: Could you elaborate on your question? Are you asking how to add another control to the form? Or how to add an "OR" clause to your filter statement? I have a blog post about filtering here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/filtering-in-angular/

Comment: WOW! very useful. I am asking how to add  "OR" clause to my filter statement so I won't need to code two different methods(or many methods for each filter) thanks! @DeborahK

Comment: Then hopefully the blog post answers your question?

Comment: @DeborahK not exactly..I am getting products and filters  from the same JSON file, and I didn't build class/component to the products/filters..(which now I believe better) I just want to ise the form I used for another filter

Answer (score 0):

Start of with adding gender prop for products  in `Stores[0].Products` as it will be used for filtering:

```
Products = [
  {
    .....
    Gender: 'Boy'
  },
  {
    ....
    Gender: 'Both'
  }
]
```

than I assume you want to select gender on page ,so you should add separate `<select>` for gender in your template so add this code below priceFilter selector in form:

```
<select name="Gender" formControlName="gender">
  <option *ngFor="let k of GenderFilter;"
    [ngValue]="k">
    {{ k.displayText }}
  </option>
</select>
```

to handle changes you need to add this select control to form group:

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      filterProduct: [''],
      gender: [''] 
})}
```

now  you also must subscribe to valueChanges of that control same as with price filter:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this._storeService.getProducts()
    .subscribe(data =>{
      this.myForm.get('filterProduct').valueChanges.subscribe(
        value => {
          console.log(value);
          this.filteredProducts = [...this.Stores[0].Products
            .filter(product => 
               product.Price >= value.lower
               && product.Price <= value.upper)]
        }
     ) 
     this.myForm.get('gender').valueChanges.subscribe( value =>
         this.filteredProducts = [...this.Stores[0].Products
            .filter(product => product.Gender === value.displayText]
     )
   });
```

Comment: Thank you vey much for you answer! I just wasn't clear, besides PriceFilter I have another filter GenderFilter that looks like:  "GenderFilter": `[
    {
      "TagId": 3,
      "Type": "Gender",
      "Value": 3,
      "Values": null,
      "DisplayText": "Boy",
      "Order": 1
    },
    {
      "TagId": 4,
      "Type": "Gender",
      "Value": 4,
      "Values": null,
       "DisplayText": "Girl",
      "Order": 2
    }  ]` the filters are different but the tagId in the product, refer to both of filters (same product will appear if it fits to the filters-price or gender)

Comment: whats the Value prop stands for in GenderFilter instance ?

Comment: in GenderFilter the value mean the TagID(if product has tag id:4 and "boy" in the genderFilter is TagId 4, the value is 4, so if selecting "boy" this product will apear) in PriceFilter the value is the PRICE of the product :)

Comment: if you just tell me, how product in this.Stores[0].Products, looks like I will edit my answer so it uses GenderFilter

Comment: [console of this.Stores[0].Products after filtering)[https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAYvr.png] (Json file)[https://i.stack.imgur.com/BapB1.png] Many thanks!

Comment: Understand the images?

Comment: yes, I am currently at work, when finished I will get back to you and try to figure it out

Comment: @Ella take a look